# Why application's driver not working in windows 10?

Tags: driver, windows-10, device-driver, minifilter, windows-10-desktop

An application's minifilter driver is working fine in windows earlier than windows 10. I want to make it work in windows 10 as well. Need help!!

I'm unable to figure out the causes in Windows 10 as the driver is perfectly working fine earlier to Windows 10 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Driver requirements ([superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/922530/windows-vista-upgrade-to-windows-10-device-driver-compatibility)) including driver signing requirements ([ms blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-hardware-certification/bg-p/WindowsHardwareCertification)) have changed in Windows 10.  You will most likely need a new driver as I think there will be no work-around for most driver problems in Windows 10.

The issue I had was due to an old audio driver and I had to manually pull down a different driver with a newer date from the hardware suppliers site.

If you want more information on the actual problem, look to the windows event log, or driver debug logs.  For example Microsoft's website says:

> If a signing problem exists, SetupAPI will log information about the signing problem in the log file. The name of this log file is SetupAPI.dev.log, and it is located, by default, in the Windows INF file directory (%SystemRoot%\inf).

Comment: I already had signed this driver but still the remaining problem exist.

Comment: Or there's a way to test driver code on Windows 10? So that I could know whether it's giving output on certain conditions.

Comment: @ArsalanHussain your comments imply that you are writing your own driver, but the question above seems like you are using some else's driver.  If you are porting a driver to Windows 10 the question should say this.